# How to implement Barcode Scanner inTitanium step by step method using zxing or any library?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

I have to implement a barcode scanner in both android and ios where I need to scan the barcode and retrieve data and bind it in the text field.

Comment: I've adjusted the title for you, since Appcelerator Studio is just an IDE, you're actually using Titanium

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one official barcode module you can look into that is fully open source. This means you can use it directly in your app on both platforms, AND you can check the source code to see how it is build, and if needed hook into that logic, expand it with your own functionality or add support for barcode types etc.

It is called ti.barcode and can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.barcode). It uses zxing under the hood as well.

Comment: how to import this module into my project?

Comment: at which specific path should this module included?

Comment: follow the examples in the repository I linked and follow the general guides for how to use modules in the docs

Answer (score 1):

You can use below hyperloop project as well which uses zxing lib directly

https://github.com/m1ga/hyperloop.barcode

Comment: I need the general guides for how to add modules to my project because I don't understand the steps